# Running a Python CGI Script with Sudo Privileges on the Apache Server

Tags: python, linux, apache, ubuntu, cgi

I am new to python CGI using Ubuntu 12.04 on the Apache 2.2.22 http server.  I am writing a script that will create other python scripts.  These created scripts must have "chmod +x" permissions to execute.  The script creating scripts must provide these permissions and I cannot figure out how to get it to do this.

In the code that creates the file, I am curious about this:

```
 os.system('sudo chmod +x %s.py' %(fname))
```

This is what attempts give the created file "chmod +x" permissions.  The os.system command does not give the created script "chmod +x" privileges perhaps because it is not run by the server with sudo privileges.  How can I get the server to give the script creating the script sudo permissions?

The complete code is below.  It is part of a user account creation system:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, os
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

# Retrieve form fields
form   = cgi.FieldStorage()                     # Get POST data
fname  = form.getfirst("fname")                 # Pull fname field data
passw  = form.getfirst("passw")                 # Pull lname field data

# Begin HTML generation
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"  # Print headers
print ""

try:
    with open('Users/%s.py' %(fname)):
            print '''
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"></linK>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <META http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=/cgi-bin/createAccount/createAccount.html">
            <meta name="keywords" content="chat, chat.ngrok.com">
            <title>Please Wait</title>
            <body bgcolor="black">
            <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Create Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">LinkHere</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="Container">
            <div class="Header"></div>
            <div id="fire">
            <br>
            <h1>Sorry, this username is already taken!</h1>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
            '''
except IOError:
    createU = open('Users/%s.py' %(fname),'w')
    createU.write('''#!/usr/bin/python
    print "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
    print ""
    print "<!DOCTYPE html>"
    print "<html>"
    print "<head>"
    print "<link media='screen' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' src='/style.css'></link>"
    print "</title>Test</title>"
    print "</head>"
    print "<body bgcolor='black'>"
    print "<div id='navbar'>"
    print "<ul>"
    print "<a href='/'>Home</a></li>"
    print "<a href='/'>About</a></li>"
    print "<a href='/'>Create Account</a></li>"
    print "<a href='/'>Login</a></li>"
    print "<a href='/'>LinkHere</a></li>"
    print "</ul>"
    print "</div>"
    print "<div class='Container'>"
    print "<div class='Header'></div>"
    print "</body>"
    print "</html>"''')
    createU.close()
    os.system('sudo chmod +x %s.py' %(fname))

    print '''
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css"></linK>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="chat, chat.ngrok.com">
    <title>Please Wait</title>
    <body bgcolor="black">
    <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Create Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">LinkHere</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="Container">
    <div class="Header"></div>
    <div id="fire">
    <br>
    <h1>Loading... Please Wait!</h1>
    </div>
    <form action="./test.py" name="FNAME" method="post">
    '''
    print '<input type="hidden" name="passw" value="%s" />' %(passw)
    print '''
    </form>
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/JavaScript">document.forms["FNAME"].submit();</SCRIPT>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''
```

Comment: Have you tried simply taking out the sudo? The reason why it's not working is that the user running this script would need to "type" their sudo password for the sudo command. But if the user running this script is creating the file anyways, it should already have permission to change the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Unfortunately, by removing sudo from os.system(), the script did not have permissions to use chmod when run by the server just as before.

Comment: BTW, as far as I can tell, your script only ever creates an empty file and never calls the chmod command at all.

Comment: If the user file does not exist, a new file is created named after a username entered in the form.  This file is, in theory, created with the except IOError code.

Comment: I think that @hop is wrong in that the script never calls the chmod. If the file doesn't exist it will through an IOError which is caught and then that is where the os call is made.

Am I correct in thinking that currently the file IS being created but the permissions are NOT being changed?

Comment: Yes, I know that the file is being created and I think that the permissions are either not being changed or the server does not have permission to change them.

Comment: Oh hey, you are creating the file in Users/ but then you try to chmod outside that directory. Shouldn't your chmod command be `os.system('chmod +x Users/%s.py' %(fname))`?

Comment: Oops...  Thanks for the help.  I totally missed that...

Comment: yeah, i saw a 'w', where there wasn't one. still… it's bad. it has a security whole the size of a barn–just imagine what happens when someone enters a filename that contains a path.

Comment: Can you give some examples of how the script is bad?  This will be helpful for writing scripts in the future.

Comment: @hop It may be bad but you weren't being constructive either, like helping tell the OP what exactly is bad and what the OP can do to improve it.

Comment: @adamk33n3r: i'm sorry, but sometimes you just have to accept the fact that you should step away from the keyboard and leave it all be.

Comment: @hop the server has been set up to give a forbidden page when an event like you described occurs

Comment: @thelonious: haha, you are funny.

Comment: @hop Thank you for the advice, can you provide insight as to how else I may fix the security problem?

Comment: @thelonious You should probably ask that as a new question.

Comment: No problem, @thelonious. I wish you luck.

Comment: Question about security at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494154/improving-the-secuity-of-a-python-cgi-script-that-creates-user-accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the file in the Users/ directory but then you try to chmod outside of that directory.

Your chmod command should be `os.system('chmod +x Users/%s.py' %(fname))`

Comment: I'm curious as to why this has gotten two down-votes on June 18th.